# SAS IML and SAS/R interface

Tags: r, sas-iml

Does one need to have SAS IML installed to use the SAS/R interface? or should/could one use the sas x command to run R and feed data to it?

Comment: one could/should try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to actually use the SAS/R interface, then yes, you [must license and have SAS/IML installed](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/65547/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_r_sect001.htm) as it is specifically a feature of SAS/IML (which makes sense, as SAS/IML is SAS's matrix programming language, and R is a matrix programming language).

However, you're welcome to use R the way you describe (by submitting R programs via `xcmd`); you will, however, need to use a CSV file or similar to exchange data between the two programs.  There are [several](http://www.sas-programming.com/2010/04/conduct-r-analysis-within-sas.html) [ways](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v46/c02/paper) [to](http://www.lexjansen.com/phuse/2005/cc/cc03.pdf) [do](http://www.sasanalysis.com/2011/05/support-vector-machine-for.html) it, so look at the different options available to see what's easiest for you.

If you're choosing between the different ways to do this, here is a list of the [advantages of using IML](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/11/25/twelve-advantages-to-calling-r-from-the-sasiml-language.html) which serves as a nice comparison between the two (perhaps a biased one (Rick is the lead developer of SAS/IML), but it is sufficiently detailed in what you won't have available to you running it as a separate program that it should be helpful in making the decision).