# What is the simplest simple SAS code to execute R script without a SAS-IML license?

Tags: python, r, sas

## How do I run R scripts from SAS without SAS-IML?

I am using SAS Enterprise Guide on a server. Since I have a background in R, I would like to be able to use R code to supplement the work I am doing in SAS.

The SAS license does not include `IML`. Thus, I cannot use `proc iml`. However, the server *does* have an R installation.

However, I've gathered from other sources—including [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51640295/how-to-create-and-use-an-r-function-in-sas-9-4) as well as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33504441/sas-iml-and-sas-r-interface)—that one can execute external scripts with SAS using the `x` command. In an email, someone indicated I can use `call execute` to execute "anything". In the same email, the person indicated that `proc fcmp` can build functions that execute Python.

This is all great to know, but I'm looking for a minimal reproducible example.

I'm fine with using .csv file intermediates for going back and forth between SAS and R.

For example, I am happy to build an R script that generates a .csv file which can later be read by SAS. *I do not want to have to open and execute R externally though*, **I want SAS to execute the R script.**

**R script that SAS should run - `simple_script_to_run_from_sas.r`**

```r
df <- data.frame(
    a = c(1, 2, 3)
    , b = c("test", "one", "two")
    )

write.csv(
    df
    , paste0(getwd(), "/test.csv")
    , row.names = F
    )
```

### What would the simplest SAS code be that would point to this R script and execute it?

A correct answer will be one that gives me simple SAS code that runs an R script. Bonus if similar code can be used to execute Python scripts (the server *also* has Python installed).

Comment: Have you checked the link [here](https://www.listendata.com/2016/09/run-r-from-sas.html)? It seems to provide a suitable SAS macro for executing `Rscript` and maybe it could be used to make something more general.